# Grep that returns string that contains only dashes and whitespace

Tags: grep

I'm trying to write grep that return strings that contains only dashes and whitespace.

For example I have such a text:

```
 instanceName                                                            comPort
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
 MS-E2E003-COM14                                                         COM14
 MS-E2E003-COM15                                                         COM15
 MS-E2E003-COM16                                                         COM16
 MS-E2E003-COM19                                                         COM19

(4 rows affected)
```

In this example the grep to return the 2nd string:
`----------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------`

"^[- ]+$" returns string only with dashes or string only with whitespace or both.

The command I use:

```
foreach rw(exec_res) { # the list contains a text
    print(grep("^[- ]+$", rw));
}
```

Comment: Please, show what is output should be from above mentioned example

Comment: Could you also paste the full command you used?

Comment: What is your question? The expression you show works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to grep for strings that contain *both* dashes and space?

In that case you need two greps, the one you have that picks out potentially correct strings, and one the removes those that only contain dashes or space:

```
grep -E '^[- ]+$' | grep -Ev '^([-]+|[ ]+)$'
```

#### Edit - how to do the same thing with perl

If you're trying to do this in perl, you can accomplish the same thing like this:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^([- ]+)$/m && $1 !~ /^([ ]+|[-]+)$/'
```

Comment: Thank you, but my grep() doesn't support "+" statements ((( "^[- ]+$" returns correct strings, but my grep() doesn't support "+" statements